# Not able to open a webview activity from a tabbed view fragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, webview, fragment

iam new to android and iam trying to create an app with a lot of websites linked on to the apps like facebook, twitter , mail etc

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.shortshop.app;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        adapter.addFrag(new FourFragment(), "FOUR");
        adapter.addFrag(new FiveFragment(), "FIVE");
        adapter.addFrag(new SixFragment(), "SIX");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
    }
```

OneFragment.java

```
    package com.shortshop.app;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;


    public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }

    }
```

fragment_one.xml

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:onClick="facebook"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook_icon" />
    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Iam not able to add this code in the OneFragment.java where i endup with error

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_one);
}
public void facebook(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

It would be great full if some comes out with a solution i have been trying to figure out the solution for so long

WebActivity.java

```
package com.shortshop.app;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WebActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebview ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mWebview  = new WebView(this);

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

        final Activity activity = this;

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mWebview .loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
        setContentView(mWebview );

    }

}
```

activity_web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.shortshop.app.WebActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: what is the error? post us the log please.

Comment: share your error log & your webActivity class

Comment: Error:(39, 25) error: incompatible types: OneFragment cannot be converted to Fragment i get his error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your OneFragment.java. post this code.

```
  @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

            ImageButton imageButton= (ImageButton ) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 Intent intent = new Intent(this, WebActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
            return view;
        }

    }
```

Comment: unfortunately, app has stopped it crashes

Comment: @KiranJC    you have to remove your onCreate and paste the above one

Comment: Error:(25, 25) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(OneFragment,Class<WebActivity>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; OneFragment cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; OneFragment cannot be converted to Context)

Comment: see the log error       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method facebook(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton with id 'imageButton'

Comment: @KiranJC now you're good. see update. If it solved your problem please accept the answer